# Blackberry - how to consume asp.net webservice having windows authentication

Tags: blackberry

We are working for Blackberry Native Application for 5.0 and above.

BB Application has to consume web service written in the ASP.Net. Web Service is secured by Windows Authentication.

We are using KSOAP library for call web service from BB.

Please let us know what is required to pass Windows Authentication from our app.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code. I am it will work with network credential password.

```
String URL = "URL"+methodName+parameterString+"deviceside=true";
connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(URL);
String authenticationParameter = "username"+":"+"password";
byte[] encoded = Base64OutputStream.encode(authenticationParameter.getBytes(), 0, 
authenticationParameter.length(), false, false);
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ new String(encoded));
rc = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Hope help full.